# Using testflight to test app prior to publish with another account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm currently developing an iOS app and I want to use TestFlight to deploy the betas. One of the requisites is that I must register the app bundle id in my apple dev account.

The final release of the app will be managed for the customer, so will be uploaded to theirs apple account.

Are there any concerns or troubles if I register the bundle app id in my account first, for testing purposes? Will the customer be able to publish the same app using her account?
I think this is a very common scenario, could you provide some alternatives or workarounds to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The bundle ID uniquely identifies an application. Two applications can not have the same bundle identifier. [Here](https://cocoacasts.com/what-are-app-ids-and-bundle-identifiers/) is more clear info about this.

If your app needs to be published by your client. You can create test credentials (bundle id, provisioning profile, developer certificate) for development environment and use your client credentials for production environment.

Another option is, once it has been published, you can [transfer](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f) the ownership of that app to your client.

Comment: Thanks Enrique. One more thing, I just realized that I can change the bundle identifier in Project properties page. May be I can use my own bundle id for testing purposes and then set the customer's bundle id prior release. Do you see this as a valid option?

Comment: Of course, I think that is the most appropriate option.

Comment: You can create different targets in your project (development / production) with their own credential configuration.