# Move an app from a Testflight account to another one

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, icloud, bundle-identifier

I'm developing an iOS app in Xcode 12.2 for a client.

The client does not have an Apple Developer account yet, so I'm using the Testflight of my own account to test the app with the designer.

The app uses AppGroups, let's say I have a group named "group.com.myorg.appname".

I'm also using CoreData, and will implement NSCloudKitContainer very soon.

My question is:

**Once the client has purchased a developer account, can I easily delete my version from my Testflight, and then add it to the client's Testflight, without issues?**

For example, do I have to change the AppGroup identifier? And is this a problem for iCloud?

---

*I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404517/14544835) which contains lots of good information, but didn't allow me to be sure about iCloud or the AppGroup identifier. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50705327/14544835) was also very useful but incomplete. I've also read information about app transfert, but in my case the app is not published, it's just in Testflight, there's no publishing before moving to the client's account.*

Comment: Hi, I am about to do the same, do you have any personal experience since? Could you share? (What is the new build number you used in the new account?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to lose the IDs, the safest option is the transfer the app to the new account rather than deleting it. If you have push notification certificates, these would need to be regenerated on the new account. However the same goes for the App Groups. You will need to delete it from your old account to release the ID and make it available for the new one. There shouldn’t be issues doing this since it is not launched yet. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70297

Comment: Thank you. I have no problem with losing the current development IDs, I just need to be sure that what I'm going to do is possible and will not cause conflicts. I understand from your answer and your link that if I remove the AppGroup ID from my account I will then be able to use it in the client's account, so that's great. I'm still not sure about the iCloud part, though.

Comment: What about the build number? Should I reset it to 1 or continue?